# What is wrong with this line of react-native realm code

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Whenever I run my program I come up with the error `unknown` on line 16

```
let zeros = realm.objects('zero', 'age >= 17');
```

I have no Idea what is wrong with it, I have played around with syntax and all sorts of variable names, yet am unable to yield a positive result.  Here is the rest of the code for reference, it is stock code from the Realm website.

```
const Realm = require('realm');

class zero {}
zero.schema = {
    name: 'zero',
    primaryKey: 'name',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
        age: {type: 'int', default: 0},
    },
};

const realm = new Realm({schema: [zero]});

// Query
let zeros = realm.objects('zero', 'age >= 17');
zeros.length // => 0

// Write
realm.write(() => {
    savedzero = realm.create('zero', {
        name: 'Hal Incandenza',
        age: 17,
    });
});

// Queries are updated in real-time
zeros.length // => 1
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

The `realm.objects()` method only accepts one argument. Instead, you want to write: `realm.objects('zero').filtered('age >= 17')`

It should be giving you a more useful error message than `unknown` however. Are you on the latest version, 0.13.2?